# I am trying to make the navbar sticky but my JQuery is not adding the css class that i want to add on scroll function

Tags: javascript, html, css

Below are the HTML, CSS, and JS code in which I am facing the problem, and not able to attain the functionality that I am supposed to.

```js
//This is where I think the prblem is but I am not able to figure out how to correct it

window(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (this.scrollY > 20) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('sticky');
    } else {

    }
  })
});
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 80px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Navbar styling */

.navbar {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", "sans-serif";
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.navbar .max-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  padding: 80px 0;
  *background: #ffffff;
}

.navbar .max-width .logo a {
  color: crimson;
}

.navbar .max-width .logo a span {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
  color: crimson;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 25px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}


/* Home Section */

.home {
  margin-top: -60px;
  display: flex;
  background: url("images/banner.png") no-repeat center;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.home .max-width {
  margin: auto 0px auto 370px;
}

.home .home-content .text-1 {
  font-size: 27px;
}

.home .home-content .text-2 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 span {
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Personal Portfolio Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script src="src=" https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js ""></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">Aksh<span>at Saxena</span></a></div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- home section start -->
  <section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="home-content">
        <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
        <div class="text-2">Akshat Saxena</div>
        <div class="text-3">And i'm a Web <span>Web Developer</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <p>Hi, I am Akshat. I have over four years of experience in WordPress website development. If you are looking for a complete high-end, up-to-date, professional, and responsive WordPress website then you are in the right place. I will develop stunning and
    captivating websites for both businesses and individuals. I would love to help you with your desire website project. Feel free to contact me, Cheers!
  </p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

While scrolling down the background of the nav-bar should turn white but it's not behaving in that way it should be behaving. What would be the easier way to attain this functionality if I am not supposed to do it this way.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any problem if the navbar is always fixed?
Add `background-color: white;` to the `.navbar` class and check if that is satisfactory. This allows you to make the navbar background white and the page text goes behind the navbar on scrolling. If that satisfies you, then you can even remove the jquery code.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```js
//This is where I think the prblem is but I am not able to figure out how to correct it

(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if (this.scrollY > 20) {
      $('.navbar').addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      $('.navbar').removeClass('sticky');
    }
  })
})();
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 80px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Navbar styling */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", "sans-serif";
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.navbar .max-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  padding: 80px 0;
  background: #ffffff;
  position: fixed;
}

.navbar .max-width .logo a {
  color: crimson;
}

.navbar .max-width .logo a span {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
  color: crimson;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 25px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}


/* Home Section */

.home {
  margin-top: -60px;
  display: flex;
  background: url("images/banner.png") no-repeat center;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.home .max-width {
  margin: auto 0px auto 370px;
}

.home .home-content .text-1 {
  font-size: 27px;
}

.home .home-content .text-2 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 span {
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Personal Portfolio Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">Aksh<span>at Saxena</span></a></div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- home section start -->
  <section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="home-content">
        <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
        <div class="text-2">Akshat Saxena</div>
        <div class="text-3">And i'm a Web <span>Web Developer</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <p>Hi, I am Akshat. I have over four years of experience in WordPress website development. If you are looking for a complete high-end, up-to-date, professional, and responsive WordPress website then you are in the right place. I will develop stunning and
    captivating websites for both businesses and individuals. I would love to help you with your desire website project. Feel free to contact me, Cheers!
  </p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

- Fixed HTML syntax (`<script>` `src`), JavaScript syntax (`})()`) and CSS syntax (`background` without *)
- In the JavaScript, remove the class again when the condition is not met
- In the CSS, set `position: fixed;` when the `.sticky` class is present, not the other way around
- Look at [`position: sticky`](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp) for a pure CSS way to do this, e.g.:

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@400;500;600;700&family=Ubuntu:wght@400;500;700&display=swap");
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.max-width {
  max-width: 1300px;
  padding: 0 80px;
  margin: auto;
}


/* Navbar styling */

.navbar {
  width: 100%;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", "sans-serif";
  padding: 80px 0;
}

.navbar .max-width {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: -webkit-sticky; /* Safari */
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar .max-width .logo a {
  color: crimson;
}

.navbar .max-width .logo a span {
  color: #000;
}

.navbar .logo a {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.navbar .menu li {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.navbar .menu li a {
  color: crimson;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin-right: 25px;
  transition: color 0.3s ease;
}

.navbar .menu li a:hover {
  color: #000;
}


/* Home Section */

.home {
  margin-top: -60px;
  display: flex;
  background: url("images/banner.png") no-repeat center;
  height: 100vh;
  min-height: 500px;
  font-family: "Ubuntu", sans-serif;
}

.home .max-width {
  margin: auto 0px auto 370px;
}

.home .home-content .text-1 {
  font-size: 27px;
}

.home .home-content .text-2 {
  font-size: 75px;
  font-weight: 600;
  margin-left: -3px;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 {
  font-size: 40px;
  margin: 5px 0;
}

.home .home-content .text-3 span {
  color: crimson;
  font-weight: 500;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Personal Portfolio Website</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/a076d05399.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <nav class="navbar sticky">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="logo"><a href="#">Aksh<span>at Saxena</span></a></div>
      <ul class="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Skills</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Teams</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contacts</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- home section start -->
  <section class="home" id="home">
    <div class="max-width">
      <div class="home-content">
        <div class="text-1">Hello, my name is</div>
        <div class="text-2">Akshat Saxena</div>
        <div class="text-3">And i'm a Web <span>Web Developer</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <p>Hi, I am Akshat. I have over four years of experience in WordPress website development. If you are looking for a complete high-end, up-to-date, professional, and responsive WordPress website then you are in the right place. I will develop stunning and
    captivating websites for both businesses and individuals. I would love to help you with your desire website project. Feel free to contact me, Cheers!
  </p>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```